# Return -1 With Empty Array

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to solve a problem in which I have to get the last index of a number in an array. I managed to do so but I also need to return -1 if the array is empty but mine returns undefined. For now I put return false because I have no clue what to do.

```js
function lastIndexOf(arr, val) {
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (arr === '') {
      return false;
    }

    return  arr.lastIndexOf(val);
  }
}

console.log(lastIndexOf([], 4));
```

Comment: What a mess! Write out how you would do it on paper and then convert to code. What you have there is just nonsense.

Comment: `function lastIndexOf(arr, val) { return arr.lastIndexOf(val); }` is all you need. Or do you not want to use the builtin array method?

Comment: I need the function to return -1 if I don’t give the array a value when I call it. Right now it returns undefined. @Bergi

Comment: So, `return Array.isArray(arr) ? arr.lastIndexOf(val) : -1;`?

Answer (score 0):

The `lastIndexOf` method is all you need here. It will return -1 if your array is empty or it doesn't contain the said value

```js
   

function lastIndexOf(arr, val) {
    return arr.lastIndexOf(val);
}

console.log(lastIndexOf([], 4));

console.log(lastIndexOf([1, 2, 6, 8], 4));

console.log(lastIndexOf([1, 2, 4, 6, 8], 4));
```